# Can I set a lagg group on 2 ports of a Dell powerConnect 2708 to connect to a Dell PowerConnect 2624 Switch?

Tags: networking

Basically I have 2 1gig connections running to another room in the house where I will have 2 servers setup. I have a managed 8port Dell PC 2708 switch there. I can setup a lagg group with any of the ports on the switch. I would like to be able to run the 2 connections into room into a lagg1 and get double the bandwidth to my 2624 Dell PC switch. Would it work or am I asking for a world of hurt here?

Reason I ask this is because I have a storage server setup with 2 1GB nics in it which I setup LACP on the LAGG and its connected right now to my 2624 switch. I like the extra speed I can get off the server as I am able to saturate the connection on reads.  Now I am planning to put my XenHost server in the same room, I want it to connect to the switch, have access to the additional bandwidth of the file server while I still can also enjoy that speed as well.

```
S1 2gbs ==> 2708 <== 2gbs ==> 2624 <-- 1gbs Client1, etc
S2 1gbs --> 2708
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see no reference to any form of management interface to the 26xx series switches, so they appear to be unmanaged.  That means you cannot set up LAGG on them.

You would require one of the 27xx series switches (like in the server room) in order to do that.

Comment: I know the 26xx  has no management interface on then, but my 2708 does.

Comment: which doesn't help when you need to set up LAGG at both ends of the link.

Comment: I get it now. oh well :)